# process bar in popup window

Tags: c#, multithreading, parameter-passing

ok I make a process bar and that works. now, I have it in a pop up window and I want it to update while some word is being done in another thread(not the main thread). Anyhow, I am trying to update the process using information from that other thread but it is not updating. I am using a for loop in the other thread and I am using the I so find what percent I have left to go.
here in my code:

```
void callPopUp()
    {
        new Thread(() => new PopUp().ShowDialog()).Start();

    }
   //___ other thread 
    bool running(int Baseline)
    {

        HomeMO();

        tcClient.WriteAny(statenumber, Int16.Parse("11"));
        while ( state != 11)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
            tcClient.WriteAny(statenumber, Int16.Parse("11"));
        }
        StepInfo step= get_StepInfo();
        int point = step.Start_Step;
        callPopUp();

        stepPass = step.degress;
        startStep = step.Start_Step;
        stopStep = step.End_Step;
        for ( int i =0; i < step.runcount; i++)
        {
            try
            {

                callPopUp(i, step);
              ...
```

now that is in my main form. here is the code in my popup form:

```
  private void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // graphics 
        g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        // clear grapthic
        g.Clear(Color.LightBlue);
        //draw progressbar
        g.FillRectangle(Brushes.CornflowerBlue, new Rectangle(0, 0,(int)(percent * pbUNit), (int)pbHEIGHT));
        // draw % complete
        g.DrawString(percent + " %", new Font("Arial", (pbHEIGHT / 2F)), Brushes.Black, new PointF((pbWIDTH/2F)-20, (pbHEIGHT/2F)-20));

        //load bitmap in picturebox
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;


        if(percent > 100)
        {
            // dispose
            g.Dispose();
            t.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

that is the timer that draws the process bar. but somehow the percent is not updating.
here is the whole form:

```
 public partial class PopUp : Form
{
    Timer t = new Timer();
    double pbUNit;
    float pbWIDTH, pbHEIGHT, pbComplete;
    Bitmap bmp;
    Graphics g;
    private int percent =0;
    public string Title;

    public int Percents
    {
        get { return percent; }
        set { percent = value; }
    }
    public PopUp()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = Title;
    }

    private void PopUp_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Text = Title;
        pbWIDTH = pictureBox1.Width;
        pbHEIGHT = pictureBox1.Height;
        pbUNit = pbWIDTH / 100.0;
        // pbComplete - this is equal to work completed in % [min = 0 max= 100]
        pbComplete = 0;

        bmp = new Bitmap((int)pbWIDTH, (int)pbHEIGHT);

        //timer
        t.Interval = 50;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(this.t_Tick);
        t.Start();}
```

again this works good if I just put in a counter in the popup form. but it does not work when I send data to the popup window.
it just stays at 0;

also, I did try .show but then the  pop up form does come up, but I cannot see my process bar at all.

Comment: You can't show popup dialog from another thread, you can only access UI elements in UI thread.

Comment: Akash Kava, that was a big help. it is working now. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't show popup dialog from another thread, you can only access UI elements in UI thread.